# How to not graph the extreme outliers in a boxplot?

Tags: r

I have an R script that uses a csv file as it's source data to create sixteen separate boxplots. Each of the sixteen boxplots have varying y-axis scales, which makes it difficult to apply a general ylim statment to the script. I tried using the coor_cartesian function with the ylim statement as well as the scale_y_continuous function, but again, that was too general to apply across sixteen boxplots with varying y-axis scales (I do not want to normalize the scales across the sixteen boxplots, only plots with 'extreme' outliers).

Below is the snipet of data I used to create the sixteen box plots. 'SE_Data' is the csv source file I noted above. I should also mention that the sixteen boxplots are exported as a single pdf file (I don't know if this level of detail is needed or not).

```
# Enter csv input file:
SE_Data<-read.csv("SE_DATA.csv",header=T)

# Enter output file name:
pdf(file="SE_Box_Plots.pdf", onefile=TRUE)

x=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H")

SE_Data$ACO_Desc <- factor(SE_Data$ACO_Desc , x) #Ensures x-axis is ordered from A through H

#Creates sixteen individual boxplots 
for (i in 5:ncol(SE_Data)) { 

  p<-ggplot(SE_Data, aes(x=Group_Desc, y=SE_Data[,i])) + geom_boxplot() +
  ylab(gsub("\\_", " ", colnames(SE_Data)[i])) + 
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 0))
  print(p)

}

dev.off()  

dev.list()
```

I wasn't sure if I would need to create an IF ELSE statment to solve this problem, however, as a someone who is still fairly new to R, this appears to be well above my skill level. Below, I included two of the sixteen boxplots to illustrate how their y-axis scales differ from eachother.

Box Plot 1:
[image: Box Plot 1]

Box Plot 2:
[image: Box Plot 2]

As you can see from the two boxplots, they both have very different y-axis scales. In my opinion 'boxplot 2' looks fine, however, 'boxplot 1' contains extreme outliers. I would to develop a piece of code that could remove these extreme values in order to reduce the amount of 'dead space' on the boxplot; thus, lowering the scale of the y-axis and making it more appealing to the eye.

It's important to stress that I still want outliers to be included in my boxplots, however, I want to remove only the extreme outliers. If you need any more information from my end please be sure to let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your graph without the data but including

```
geom_boxplot( outlier.shape=NA )
```

should hide the outliers. You can manually adjust the yscale with

```
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-5, 1)) # or whatever values you want to use.
```

Comment: this is helpful, however, the scale from the scale_y_continuous function is applied across all boxplots. Is there a way the I can adjust the scale on a per plot basis? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. You could try faceting by Group_Desc and using scales = 'free_y'